# How to use query scripts as IQueryable or DBSet in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable, sql-scripts

I'm using entity framework code first to query database,
the problem is I'm not allowed to create views in the database,
so I should use query scripts in my codes. I want this query script to be considered same as DBSet or IQueryable by entity framework so that I can apply linq queries on it.
I don't want it to be IEnumerable so 'Database.SqlQuery' doesn't work for me.

example: 
there is Product table in db, which contains {Id,Name,CategoryId}
and there is Category table in db, which contains {Id,Name}

my query script is like this:

```
select Id,Name,CategoryId,CategoryName
from Product p
join Category c on p.CategoryId=c.Id
```

I want to use this query in my code, as if it was a view.

Any idea?

ps: The query script is so complicated that I cannot build it with Linq.

***I solved this problem using Interceptor*,
Here is the solution:**

1. Create a Dbset in your context like this:
   `public DbSet<Model.MyView> MyViews { get; set; }`
2. Create DbCommandInterceptor, and apply it to your entity framework configuration
3. In the Interceptor implement this method:
   `public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)` 
   , and modify the command text like this:
   `command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("[dbo].[MyViews]", "(" + MyViewScript + ")");`

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw SQL queries with EF:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx